# Does dungeon level affect Create Familiar spell?

Tags: neth

I recently learned and am able to reliably cast Create Familiar.  It's one of the few spells that I've never really used before. The wiki says that casting it at high levels (XL?) can create strong pets. Will casting it in deeper levels (or a special area, like Gehennom or a graveyard) affect which monsters are generated like Create Monster?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this as Nethack?